# Completing The Cubic of $f(x) = x^3 + 2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to write $f(x) = x^3 + 2x$ in 'completing the cubic' form [like we do in 'completing the square' for quadratic function]

Comment: You may look for Cardano Formula if you are interested but in general it is not practical to use such formula.

Comment: Do you want isolate x in that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the idea is isolate $x$ Note that
$$y=x^3+2x\implies x^3+2x-y=0$$
In the last equatión use the cubic formula or Cardano fórmula
[Cubic (Cardano) Formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)

Answer (score 2):

You could write it as:

$x^3+2x=x^3+3x^2+3x+1-3x^2-x-1=(x+1)^3-3x^2-x-1$

I doubt, that there is a specific method to complete a cubic, in the sense, that you get it in the form $x^3+2x=a(x+e)^3+f$

Edit: In fact, if you write the equation above as

$x^3+2x=ax^3+3aex^2+3e^2x+e^3+f$

and now compare the coefficients on both sides, we see $a=1$. Also $e=0$, since there is no $x^2$ on the RHS. 
This leads to $x^3+f$ on the LHS, which is already wrong, so no such form exists here.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean.

Completing the square for a quadratic $f(x)$ means finding an expression
$$f(x)=(ax+b)^2+c\ ,$$
where $a,b,c$ are constants.

The obvious generalisation to a cubic is to look for $a,b,c$ such that
$$f(x)=(ax+b)^3+c\ .$$
If $f(x)=x^3+2x$ then expanding the right hand side and equating coefficients gives the equations
$$a^3=1\ ,\quad 3a^2b=0\ ,\quad 3ab^2=2\ ,\quad b^3+c=0\ .$$
But these equations have no solution ($3a^2b=0$ means that $a=0$ or $b=0$, then $3ab^2=0$ which contradicts $3ab^2=2$).

Therefore completing the cube in this sense is impossible for your example.  It would be possible for certain examples, e.g.,
$$x^3+6x^2+12x+13=(x+2)^3+5\ .$$

Comment: Do you not want to find $f(x)=a(x+b)^2+c$ when completing a square?

Comment: Since completing a square for a function like -x^2+1 would not be possible, if you write it as $(ax+b)^2+e$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation ... I need to find another way to find the inverse of this f(x) ... Trying decomposing the function f(x) = g[h(x)] etc .. and even try to find the inverse on product of two function f(x) = g(x).h(h) ... but can find any way to solve [g(x).h(x)]^(-1).

Comment: @hafaba What exactly are you asked to do? What are g(x) and h(x)? You can find an inverse by solving a specific equation (if possible).

Comment: @Cornman
Given f(x) = x^3 + 2x
So f(x) = x(x^2 + 2)

f(x) = h(x) . g(x) where h(x) = x and g(x) = x^2 + 2 [Assuming domain of x given such that g(x) is one-to-one function, there exist inverse of g(x)]

inverse of f(x) = inverse of [g(x).h(x)]
= is there a way to find the inverse of this product like we have for composite function?